# How to get the Grid Size in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I had a   div id ("mydivid"), in which i'm able to successfully get the Json result into it. But my problem is - When the Json result size is zero, i want to show the message like - "Result size is zero" . If the size is greater than than zero. As Usual it will display the content in it.

```
$("#mydivid").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1,url : URL}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer.

It can be done using the isEmptyObject method, passing the response as input argument.

```
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(response)) {
                jQuery("#gbox_"+divId).hide();
                jQuery("#no_record_found").html("Result size is zero");
                $("#test").removeAttr("disabled");

                if(callback!= null)
                    callback();

            }
```